# Determine is tab is visible in TabControl Class (System.Windows.Forms)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I'm using a TabControl in a Winforms app and need to identify if all tabs are visible or if some tabs are not displaying and need the Scroll bar to get to them?

I notice the scroll bar only displays when some are not displayed, so maybe a way to identify if scroll bar is visible would work.

thanks

Comment: If the page is not displayed its Visible property will be false.

Comment: Use TabControl.GetTabRect(), it won't be inside the ClientRectangle when it is not visible to the user.

Comment: @TaW Unfortunately there is no Visible property

Comment: @HansPassant Great that did it thanks....

Comment: _there is no Visible property_ Of course there [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabpage.visible?view=netcore-3.1) but it only tells you if that tabpage is selected. The docs are wrong imo is stating that _This member is not meaningful for this control._ but it indeed  won't help you.